# Typescript error: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Error' has no index signature"

Tags: typescript

The code is here:

```
app.use((req: express.Request,
         res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  let err = new Error('Not Found');
  err['status'] = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

The error is here:

`src/server.ts(23,3): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Error' has no index signature.`

Since Error is a default global type, I don't know how I could deal with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript considers that Error as any and you are trying pass an index.Try this,

```
 app.use((req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) => {
                let err: any = new Error('Not Found');
                err.status = 404;
                next(err);
            });
            let error = new ectrl.ErrorController();
            app.use('*', error.errorAction);
            return app;
}
```

where your ectrl is

```
export module Controller {
    export class ErrorController extends ctrl.Controller {

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        errorAction(err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
            let data = {
                message: err.message,
                error: err,
                title: err.message,
                layout: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views', 'layouts', 'layout.hbs')
            };
            res.status(err.status || 500);
            res.render('error/error', data);
        }
    }
}
```